# Setting Email based on contents of an editable Div

Tags: javascript, html

I am unsure if I am using the right approach, or if I should be setting up my editable div as a form. I have a selectbox for the email recipient. I just want the contents of the div to fill the body of the email. Is it possible to have javascript populate the body to the HREF dynamically? This is clearly broken

```
<div class="editable" id="emailbody">

  </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Editable div
$('.editable').each(function(){
    this.contentEditable = true;
});
</script>
  <span id="OUTLWP"></span>
  <span id="outreason"></span>

<span class="OUTBPC"></span>
</div>

<input LANGUAGE="JavaScript" TYPE="button" VALUE="Send email"
ONCLICK="location.href = &quot;mailto:&quot; +
document.myform.mylist.options[document.myform.mylist.selectedIndex].value +&quot;?subject=This            is the Subject+&amp;body=getElementbyID("emailbody")&quot;"
NAME="Send email">
</div>
```

Comment: You are using a </script> closing tag without opening tag, in 3rd line. Also, you are not closing the input tag in the end. Also, I highly doubt that what you are doing in location.href works.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the `input` button to an `<a>` tag and adjust the href within a click handler

```
<a id="send_email">Send Email</a>
```

JS

```
$('#send_email').click(function (e) {
    var subject = 'My Email Subject';
    this.href = 'mailto:' + $('#myList').val() + '?subject='+subject+'&body=' + $('#emailbody').html();
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/e72vudn4/1)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

1) Since you're using jquery, you might as well use it for everything...

2) It's better to call a function in the onclick event that to try and code a whole function

3) attributes use camelCase within HTML tags

I didn't test this, but it should get you what you need.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// Editable div
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.editable').each(function(){
        this.contentEditable = true;
    });
});

function sendMail(){
    var str = "mailto:" + 
    $('#mylist').val() +
    "?subject=This is the Subject" +
    "&body=" + $('#emailbody').text();

    window.open(str);
}
</script>

<div class="editable" id="emailbody">
    <span id="OUTLWP"></span>
    <span id="outreason"></span>
    <span class="OUTBPC"></span>
</div>

<input type="button" value="Send email" onclick="sendMail()" name="Send email" />
```